# Is it possible to read/open an user key (those key in HKEY_USERS and start with s-1-5-21xxx) after that user logoff

Tags: c++, visual-c++, registry

I'd like to know if I can find particular user's registry after that user logoff?

I notice that after user logs off, that corresponding key int `HKEY_USERS` will disappear (For example, `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-245205834-4096572605-1844777647-1002` correspond to user account `AAA`, after `AAA` logs off this key will disappear, too).

This registry contains some information I need, so I want to read/open it no matter user login or not, I'd like to do it in C/C++ way, and I appreciate any possible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A user's registry configs are stored in `NTUSER.DAT` file. This file can give you the desired user's `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`. The file is stored in the user's profile directory.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776892(v=vs.85).aspx),

> A registry hive. The registry hive is the file NTuser.dat. The hive is
>   loaded by the system at user logon, and it is mapped to the
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER registry key. The user's registry hive maintains the
>   user's registry-based preferences and configuration.

**Note:** The file is locked if already mounted i.e., if the user is logged-in, you can not access the file. So, before loading the file, you should check by opening the respective `HKCU` if user is logged-in or not.

Good Read: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d0d485b8-c3d1-49d0-8180-0515d9cfb04e/read-and-modify-ntuserdat-file?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll give it a try

Comment: My pleasure. You can accept the answer if it is what you were looking for.

Comment: Sorry for reply you so late. I'm trying hard to check those information in _NTuser.dat_. I have two _NTuser.dat_ in my computer. First is in **C:\Users\Public**, and the others is in **C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile**, but after hive them, neither of them have information that I'm looking for, the _NTuser.dat_ in **C:\Users\Public** is empty like this [link](https://imgur.com/a/0fMCq)

Comment: By the way, Sorry I didn't notice that your answer is about **HKCU**. I'm not finding the information from **HKCU**, I'm looking for **HKU**. If _NTUSER.DAT_ contains information only about **HKCU**. It might not be the answer I'm looking for

Comment: Open the respective User's profile, like, if the username is `Test`, then you can find the user's profile at `C:\Users\Test`. Try to load the `NTUser.dat`, `NTUser.dat.LOG1 (if the file exists)`, `NTUser.dat.LOG2 (if the file exists)`. And it will be better to load these hives under some `Temp` key created under `HKLM`.

Comment: For your doubt on `HKU vs HKCU`, you can just google it or look into this link - https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/22793529/Difference-between-HKEY-Current-User-and-HKEY-USERs.html

Comment: Although I can't hive `NTUser.dat.LOG1` and I don't have `NTUser.dat` file in the directory you said, My `NTUser.dat` only in two place, one is in `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile`, the other is in `C:\Users\Public`. still thanks for your patience.

Comment: That can't be possible. Either you haven't created the user successfully or you are browsing to the wrong location. Can you log-in with the account of user you want to process data of and post the screenshot of his user profile directory?

Comment: [Here](https://imgur.com/K1jMckH), and [this](https://imgur.com/H7wArAD) is what happened after I'm trying to hive `NTUser.dat.LOG1`

Comment: And I have two more account (state : logs off), [here](https://imgur.com/Iudqm1N) and [here](https://imgur.com/a/TUiVU), there is no `NTUser.dat`, too.

Comment: Your solution work fine in OS `WinXP`, I really appreciate that you let me have this new knowledge.

Comment: :-) Solution lies in the plain sight. You have to uncheck the option `Hide protected OS files` under `Folder Options` to view the file.